# how to invite a friend to the application

Tags: silverlight, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Hi
I'm trying to develop a simple application in Silverlight to the facebook, I'm using the facebook C# SDK to be able to establish the connection.

I wonder if there is any instruction FQL to invite a friend to the application and keep track of "who invited who" and also if there is any field in FQL to save, for example, the high score of my friends who share the application

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use requests to send an invite. See [this article](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/453) for more information.

Comment: thanks a lot, know i just have to find a way to integrate this in my Silverlight application